# Accessing the value of the variable defined locally in the method in action class in jsp using Struts2

Tags: java, jsp, jakarta-ee, struts2

I am trying to access the value of the variable defined in the method in the action class in jsp using Struts2.
I have a variable defined desc_map in the method of the action class.I want to access the value of this in jsp.
How can I do it?
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a public getter for the property, preferably named correctly as per the JavaBean spec:

```java
public TheType getDescMap() {
    return desc_map;
}
```

Access it from the JSP:

```
${descMap}
```

Or if you need escaping, can't use JSP 2.0+, etc:

```html
<s:property value="descMap"/>
```

All of this is covered in essentially every Struts 2 tutorial.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.However,when I display the result in jsp it does not display nething.

Comment: @Soham That's how you do it; if it isn't working, there's some other issue.

Comment: <table>
<s:iterator value="desc_map">
<tr>
<td><s:property value="key"/>:</td>
<td><s:property value="value"/></td>
</tr>
</s:iterator>
</table>

Comment: this is how I display the value in jsp.

Comment: @Soham Yeah, no, update the question, don't try to wedge code into comments. Please delete those, and edit the question. Note that what *you* have in your iterator value is *not* what I said to do, so I have no idea if you're doing it right.